# Adding zero when concatenating year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two int fields representing year and month named `s_yr` and `s_mnt`.

I would like to have a query that can concatenate these and return something like this: **201301** but I’m getting **20131** for all months from Jan to Sep.

Here is the query I use. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
select convert(varchar(4), s_yr) + convert(varchar(2), y_mnt) AS Year_Month
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using RIGHT function for this

```
select convert(varchar(4), s_yr) 
   + right('0'+ convert(varchar(2), s_mnt),2) AS Year_Month
```